# Get the field having same value in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document in my mongo db collection :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
"ID" : "a_11",
"details_list" : [
    {
        "detail" : "detail_1",
        "link" : "https://xxxxx/yyy"
    },
            
    {
        "detail" : "detail_2",
        "link" : "https://xxxxx/zzz"
    }
],
"name" : "xyz"
}
```

I want to get the "name" of all other docs where details_list (which is list of dictionary itself) matches with any other document in the same collection.

I tried using $where clause as well. db.collection.find({"$where": details_list == details_list}) but it did not returned any value.

Comment: Can you be more specific about `matches with`?  It it a match if the same objects are present and have exactly the same fields in the same order?

Comment: @Joe yeah I want to match "details_list" in such a way that it matches with other documents in same collection which have same value for "detail_list" (which is a list of dict).  Example - If document_1 has a detail_list as [{detail_1, link_1}, {detail_2, link_2}], than I need to find rest of the documents which has same value for detail_list ( [{detail_1, link_1}, {detail_2, link_2}]).